# Open/Activate an closed Application on a remote machine through pssh in Mac os10.12.6

Tags: shell, ssh, osx-mountain-lion, pssh

I was trying to open an application remotely using below command, but I get an error

```
pssh -h node.txt -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l mapsadmin -i "open /Applications/FusionX.app"
```

Below is error:

```
Stderr: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/FusionX.app
```

**mapsadmin** is the user with root privileges, still couldn't get luck. Please help me in solving this.

I have tried with AppleScript also, but no luck

```
pssh -h node.txt -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l mapsadmin -i "osascript -e 'tell application \"FusionX\" to activate'"
[1] 16:07:31 [FAILURE] <IP address> Exited with error code 1
Stderr: 30:38: execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)
```

Help me in solving this. Is there anything else to be enabled on remote machine to let this happen?

Comment: Did you give any of the suggestions below a try ?

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred to leave this as a comment, but it was too long.  However, I fear this may not be a complete answer, as the causes of the error are myriad, but I hope this might help.

First, ssh into your remote machine using the standard `ssh` command (or go to the machine physically and open *Terminal*).  Now see if are you able to run the application from there using `open /Applications/FusionX.app`.  If this throws the same error, then see if you can run the actual binary file located in */Applications/FusionX.app/Contents/MacOS*

```
cd /Applications/FusionX.app/Contents/MacOS
./FusionX
```

(Assuming the binary file located in that folder is called *FusionX*.  If not, adjust the line above accordingly.)

If that doesn't run the application, run this command:

```
chmod +x ./FusionX
```

then attempt to run the binary again.  If that works, exit from secure shell or return to your local machine and attempt to run your `pssh` command again.  I'm **hoping** this might solve your issue.

Also, you could try pure AppleScript to launch the application remotely using a command like

```
tell application "FusionX" of machine "eppc://remote_ip_or_hostname" to activate
```

(This requires *Remote Apple Events* turned **On** on the remote machine (under *System Preferences > Sharing*) and assumes FusionX is Apple-scriptable.)

Obviously, the limitation here is having to specify this command for each remote machine individually rather than through a single parallel command targetting multiple hosts.